# SpatiaLite ST_Transform does not return geometry in QGIS virtual layer

Tags: qgis, spatialite, virtual-layer

I am using the following query to SpatiaLite in a QGIS virtual layer but it is returning null geometries (looking to transform from ESPG:4326/WGS 84 to ESPG:27700/OSGB 1936):

```
SELECT st_transform(p.geometry, 27700) AS geometry FROM waypoints AS p
```

The layer "waypoints" has valid geometry (in ESPG: 4326) and the following works as expected:

```
SELECT p.geometry AS geometry FROM waypoints AS p
```

I need to do the transform as I'm hoping to use st_distance between geometries in this layer and those in a ESPG:27700 layer.

What have I missed?

Comment: 4326 might require datum transformation for OSGB 1936 BNG.

Comment: Is that possible using spatialite within QGIS?